# Prepend every array element with a sequential number in Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, sequence

Given an array in Bash, is there a simple and efficient way to prepend numbers for each element sequentially?

**Note: Adding commas bellow just to make arrays more readable!**

Example, given:

```sh
my_array=(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Desired as result:

```sh
my_array=(1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d, 5, e)
```

Or getting lines from a command result, where every line would be an element, have a number prepended before each item:

```sh
readarray -t my_array < <(my_command)
```

If there was a way to expand the array indexes along with the elements it would work for what I need, but I didn't found anything like this.

Comment: Is you intention to have comma in array elements? `but I didn't found anything like this.` Really?

Comment: @KamilCuk No, no comma. I just added the comma to make it more visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution should be fast:

```
my_array=(a, b, c, d, e)  tmp=()
for ((i=0;i<${#my_array[@]};++i)); do
   tmp+=("$((i+1))," "${my_array[i]}")
done
my_array=("${tmp[@]}")
declare -p my_array
# would output:
# declare -a my_array=([0]="1," [1]="a," [2]="2," [3]="b," [4]="3," [5]="c," [6]="4," [7]="d," [8]="5," [9]="e")
```

If the `,` behind numbers is not relevant, you may use a neat trick with `sed` in your readarray command:

```
readarray -t my_array < <(printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]}" | sed =)
```

Comment: Or, iterate over the array indices: `for i in "${!my_array[@]}"`